# Django, What is the advantage of Modifying a model manager’s initial QuerySet?

Tags: django

The below model have EditorManager,

```
   
class EditorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(role='E')

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('A', _('Author')), ('E', _('Editor'))])
    people = models.Manager()
    editors = EditorManager()
```

If I query `Person.objects.filter(role='E')` or `Person.editors.all()` I gets same result.

then, Why do we go for writing EditorManager() ?

The above code is from Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/).

Comment: You can use *custom managers* as a shortcut to complex queries that will be called very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset):

> using multiple managers on the same model. You can attach as many `Manager()` instances to a model as you’d like. This is a non-repetitive way to define common “filters” for your models.

Since you just have one action, it may be hard for you to see the benefits. However, as your code gets larger, say:

```py
good = Book.objects.filter(author="PersonA", stars=5).order_by("-date_created").exclude(outdated=True)
normal = Book.objects.filter(author="PersonA", stars=3).order_by("-date_created").exclude(outdated=True)
bad = Book.objects.filter(author="PersonA", stars=1).order_by("-date_created").exclude(outdated=True)
```

You can see that's an awful lot of code. With managers, you can do something like this:

```py
class AuthorAManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(author="PersonA").order_by("-date_created").exclude(outdated=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    # ...
    author_a = AuthorAManager()
```

```py
good = Book.author_a.filter(stars=5)
normal = Book.author_a.filter(stars=3)
bad = Book.author_a.filter(stars=1)
```

Overall, it can make your code look a lot cleaner and understandable. As you said, you can't see the difference right now as you haven't gone into complex/repeating handles, but as your project expands, I'd say it's a worthwhile investment.